# Getting Mercurial to run in Windows

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm a fan of Mercurial and have been using it on Linux for a few years. Does anyone have any experience getting this installed and running on Windows Vista? The only installation instructions that I've found look overly complicated. Does anyone have a decent checklist built from their own personal experience?

Thanks

Chris

**Follow-up:
After a few weeks usage, I can say that Mercurial on Windows works pretty well with tortoise.  The one problem I found is that push performance seemed to be much slower than on linux. 


I also discovered that cygwin has a port.**

Comment: If you are installing the client - the posts below cover the topic very well.  If you're looking to host a shared server, that's a different story.

I'm currently in the middle of updating a short install guide for getting the web interface working on a Windows server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home). I use it on my development environment at work (which is Windows XP) all the time and have had absolutely no problems with it. Even better, it comes with everything you need bundled in.

Comment: I use TortoiseHg as well. The one thing you have to watch out for is 64 bit. I use 64 bit Vista. You have to create a 32 bit Explorer shortcut for the TortoiseHg shortcut menu to work.

On 64 bit Vista just create a shortcut with the target:
%Systemroot%\SysWOW64\explorer.exe /separated

Comment: Nowadays TortoiseHg works fine on 64-bit without any extra effort.

Answer (score 5):

> *I use TortoiseHg as well. The one thing you have to watch out for is 64 bit. I use 64 bit Vista. You have to create a 32 bit Explorer shortcut for the TortoiseHg shortcut menu to work. On 64 bit Vista just create a shortcut with the target: %Systemroot%\SysWOW64\explorer.exe /separated*

Starting with version 0.8 (released 2009-07-01) TortoiseHg supports Windows Vista 64bit explorer shell integration. Thanks to the new C++ shell extension (I contributed significantly to that).

Check current release TortoiseHg-0.8.1-hg-1.3.1.exe available from http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

How about using these [installers](http://mercurial.berkwood.com/) ?

If I remember correctly it will install without any problems, and then you will have hg command which you can use on command-line, just like in Linux. At least the client side works without any problems, I have not tried to run any mercurial servers.

Comment: Have you used these yourself? Just curious because it looks like a third-party building them - just paranoid!

Chris

Comment: Well, the page is linked from main mercurial site: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/BinaryPackages . I have installed them and toyed with some commands, but I have not done any   "real work" with them.

Comment: And maybe you need to have <a href="http://www.activestate.com/activepython/">python</a> installed. I am not sure.